# Highchart xAxis tick not starting at first data point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm having an issue where I wan't the x-axis to start at December 31st and not January 1st.  I tried setting the x-axis min and using dateTimeLabelFormats, but nothing seems to change the date the ticks start at.

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            rotation: 300,
            //formatter: function () {
            //return this.value;
            //}
        },
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            year: '%m/%d/%Y'
        },
        //minTickInterval: 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        min: Date.UTC(2004, 11, 31)

    },
```

I put my code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3nr0kgt/1/).

Comment: What should the second tick be? January 31st?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use `tickPositioner`, for example this way: http://jsfiddle.net/t3nr0kgt/2/

```js
        tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
            var axis = this,
                options = axis.options,
                // get normalized tick interval
                normalizedTickInterval = axis.normalizeTimeTickInterval(
                    axis.tickInterval, 
                    options.units
                ),
                // get default ticks
                ticks = axis.getTimeTicks(
                    normalizedTickInterval, 
                    min, 
                    max, 
                    options.startOfWeek,
                    axis.ordinalPositions,
                    axis.closestPointRange,
                    true
                );

            // register information for label formatter
            ticks.info = {
                higherRanks: normalizedTickInterval.higherRanks,
                unitName: normalizedTickInterval.unitName
            };

            // replace first label with 2004 year. 
            // When labels overlap, remove for example first two elements (1 change to 2):
            ticks.splice(0, 1, min);

            return ticks;
        }
```

As you can see, that won't preventing labels overlapping so be cautious using this.

**Another solution** is to set `min` option like you did, but with `startOnTick` option. But that will create some gap: http://jsfiddle.net/t3nr0kgt/5/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help.  Where did you find all the information on the tickPositioner?  I ended up cheating and just used the formatter to add "12/31" to the front of the year value.

Comment: Well.. I work for [Highstoft](http://www.highcharts.com/about) ;) - all extra info comes directly from the source code.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen for getting this to work. Amazing, thank you! Surprising that this is such a difficult thing to get right.

Comment: My answer is a bit outdated now. I mean, that [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) provides info about ticks now (using `this.tickPositions`). Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q9zds4mg/